# How to display the value of an XML in a PDF using c#?

Tags: c#, xml, pdf

I've already created this but i want to display that same value in a PDF using c#. This code already prints the name of the given id, i'm going to print the rest of the information but this time in a PDF.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    string str = @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
                    <information>
                    <details>
                    <id>01</id>
                    <empname>qwer</empname>
                    <empid>001</empid>
                    <dept>Accounts</dept>
                    <date>2011-01-15 12:21:25</date>
                    </details>
                    <details>
                    <id>02</id>
                    <empname>jdfklgd</empname>
                    <empid>002</empid>
                    <dept>Finance</dept>
                    <date>2011-01-20 10:21:25</date>
                    </details>
                    </information>";

    var str1 = XElement.Parse(str);

    //Search ID
    string searchID = "01";

    //Get Result
    var result = str1.Elements("details").Where(x => x.Element("id").Value.Equals(searchID)).ToList();

    if(result.Count() > 0)
    {
        //Get Specific element value
        string s = result[0].Elements("empname").FirstOrDefault().Value;           
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is this question about `How to generate a PDF?` ?

Comment: You need to first save value to a pdf and then open that pdf.

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Comment: @GabrielTakyie If the question is *How to generate a PDF?* why do you put all that needless noise into the question? It does not matter how you get the values to output in a PDF

Comment: the yes that i first mentioned is to @Learner

Comment: if the result is to generate a pdf with the values, then that is what i am seeking @sirRufo

Comment: So i'm just not getting any help here?

Answer (score 1):

There are several free and paid libraries that help manipulating PDF files. Please check some of the links attached below:

http://www.pdfonline.com/easypdf/sdk/programming-pdf/csharp/index.htm?gclid=Cj0KEQjwldzHBRCfg_aImKrf7N4BEiQABJTPKNpoGdDv8TdjZ3oOrEaR3_qe3r9a_4F260Iu-O3brP8aAr5S8P8HAQ

http://nyveldt.com/blog/post/Introducing-RazorPDF

http://itextpdf.com/

http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/

Best of luck.

Comment: thank you very much i'm surely going to check those out.

Comment: @GabrielTakyie Glad I could help. If the answer suits your interests and goal, please accept it. Thanks.